# (Python) Netmiko : Compare the configuration of a router with a template

Tags: python-3.x, networking, paramiko, netmiko

I want to do a comparison between a router configuration and template which is in a txt file using netmiko library.

using the "show run" command to display all the router configuration, the comparison must be done block by block for example: the "access-list snmp" block from the output of the command with the "access-list snmp" block from template etc because some permet x.x.x.x are repeated in 3 ACL and I have to check that they are in these 3 ACL.

I don't know how to do this comparison, if you have any ideas please help me.

I tried to do it with this code but here the comparison is done line by line :

```
cisco = { 
   'device_type': 'cisco_ios', 
   'host': 'router', 
   'username': 'admin', 
   'password': 'cisco123', 
   } 
   
try
    ssh = ConnectHandler(**cisco)
    ssh.send_command('terminal length 0')
    output = ssh.send_command("show run")

except Exception as e:
    # exceptions

try:
            
    template_file = open("template.txt", "r")
    for l in file:     
        line = l.strip()
        if line not in output:
            f = open("ligne_not_in_config.txt", "a")
            f.write(l, "is not in config\n")

    except FileNotFoundError as e:
        # exceptions
```

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking for to compare/analyse a textual piece of information. You do not have [tag:networking] nor [tag:paramiko] nor [tag:netmiko] question.

Comment: Try CiscoConfParse https://github.com/mpenning/ciscoconfparse

Answer (score 0):

My sample code comparing two lists in notepad is as follows. You can use this.

```
ARBOR = []
with open('MO_ARBOR.txt') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
   lines2 = "".join(lines)
   lines3 = lines2.split("/32")
   lines4 = "".join(lines3)
   lines5 = lines4.strip()
   lines6 = lines5.split()
   #print(lines6)

with open('UPE_PUBLIC.txt') as f:
    lines10 = f.readlines()
    lines20 = "".join(lines10)
    lines30 = lines20.replace("\n",",")
    lines30 = lines30.split(",")

while '' in lines30:  # A method that removes specific characters. (for example "" > empty)
    lines30.remove('')

for i in lines30:
    if i in lines6:
        print(i + ":Tanım Var")
        with open('var.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(i +" "+"OK"+"\n")
    else:
        print(i + ":Tanım Yok")
        with open('yok.txt', 'a') as f:
            f.write(i +" "+"NOK"+"\n")
```